# Get all documents from a collection from Cloud Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, collections, get

I need to get all documents from a collection in firestore.
I've been spending hours on trying it but with no results...

My app is under NodeJS 12.
This is what i've found :

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();

const snapshot = db.collection('metrages').get();
snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
  console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
});
```

But it says that "require is not defined".

Does anybody knows how to do that?

Comment: Is this in your node js backend file?

Comment: it's in my main.js, the main javascript file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you are trying to execute this script inside a browser. This script needs to be executed in the terminal. i.e `node main.js`

Please note that node.js is a server-side Javascript execution environment that combines the V8 Javascript engine with a bunch of server-side libraries. require() is one such feature that node.js adds to the environment. So, when you run node in the terminal, you are running an environment that contains require(). require() is not a feature that is built into the browser. That is a specific feature of node.js, not of a browser. So, when you try to have the browser run your script, it does not have require(), hence the exception.

Comment: @fluflu Is this answer true? Were you trying to get all the documents from Firestore from the web browser or were you using some other environment? Please let us know, so we can assist you.